Git pull is showing me "Already up to date" even though my branch is not in sync with the remote
I had a project working with Git and encountered a phenomenon whereby running git pull returned the following message:
Already up to date.

My local branch content differs from the contents found in the remote.
For example,
A colleague committed changes to the remote branch, though these didn't happen in my local copy after the pull.
I have the different history of the branch seen in my local repository from that seen on the actual remote repository, including lost commits.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Checked the branch I was working on with git branch.
Checked the repository URL of the remote using git remote -v to match the actual repository.
It compares the commit history with git log on my local and remote branches.

Here's what I suspect is going on:
My local branch is ahead of the remote branch. The remote might have changes that git pull doesn't pick up on.

Your observations indicate that your local branch really is up to date with the remote.

Although it's possible that this is a bug in Git it's more likely that
you compare 2 different branches. Show the exact commands you use to
checkout the branch and list remote branches and include output of
git diff @{u} on your local branch you want to synchronize with the
remote.
